# ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an issue with a script and I would appreciate if someone could help.

Here is the issue:

ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length
System.String.Substring (System.Int32 startIndex, System.Int32 length) (at <9577ac7a62ef43179789031239ba8798>:0)

The script is:

```
 public class ColorTypeConverter
 {
     public string ToRGBHex(Color c)
     {
         return string.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", ToByte(c.r), ToByte(c.g), ToByte(c.b));
     }
 
     private static byte ToByte(float f)
     {
         f = Mathf.Clamp01(f);
         return (byte)(f * 255);
     }
     
    private int HexToDec (string hex)
    {
        int dec = System.Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
        return dec;
    }
    
    private float HexToFloatNormalized(string hex) {
        return HexToDec(hex) / 255f;
    }

    public Color GetColorFromString(string hexString) {
        float red = HexToFloatNormalized(hexString.Substring(0, 2));
        float green = HexToFloatNormalized(hexString.Substring(2, 2));
        float blue = HexToFloatNormalized(hexString.Substring(4, 2));
        return new Color(red, green, blue);
    }
 }
```

Ui manager script:

```
string s = PlayerPrefs.GetString("savecolorground");
ColorTypeConverter col = new ColorTypeConverter();
if(s != "")
    ground.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = col.GetColorFromString(s);
else
    ground.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = col.GetColorFromString("FFFFFF");
```

Player script:

```
ColorTypeConverter colCon = new ColorTypeConverter();
string color = PlayerPrefs.GetString("savecolor");  
if(color != "")
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = colCon.GetColorFromString(color);
else
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = colCon.GetColorFromString("2AFCFF");

GetComponent<TrailRenderer>().startColor = new Color(
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color.r, 
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color.g, 
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color.b, 
    255);
```

Comment: Well, what's the value of `hexstring`? And is it at least 6 characters long?

Comment: That edit doesn't anwser the question. Make sure that `hexstring` is at least 6 characters long, when you call `GetColorFromString()`. Obviously currently it's not, because that is, what the error message is telling you.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! If you don't use that language don't use that tag. Also just because you use a certain IDE (`visual-studio`) doesn't automatically mean that this question is about that IDE

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the [`ColorUtility`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ColorUtility.html) which already provides all this in

[`ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGB`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGB.html)

> Returns the color as a hexadecimal string in the format "RRGGBB".

and

[`ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString.html)

> Attempts to convert a html color string.
>
> Strings that begin with '#' will be parsed as hexadecimal in the following way:
>
> - #RGB (becomes RRGGBB)
> - #RRGGBB
> - #RGBA (becomes RRGGBBAA)
> - #RRGGBBAA

So you want to use

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString(KEY, "#" + ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGB);
```

and

```
Color color;

if(!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(KEY) && ColorUtility.TryParse(PlayerPrefs.GetString(KEY), out color)
{ 
    color = DEFAULT_COLOR;
}
```